# width:auto floating divs problem (IE6)

Tags: html, css

I need the text in these floating divs to be in one line. In Firefox this works ok. In IE6 it looks messed up:

[screen](http://img169.imageshack.us/img169/5800/bladie.jpg)

I cannot set an explicit width on these. Setting height does not help. Any ideas please?

The HTML:

```
<div id="wraper">

<div class="draggable">
    <p>a main road with fast-travelling traffic</p>
</div>

<div class="draggable">
    <p>a very large bird, not able to fly</p>
</div>

<div class="draggable">
    <p>very important</p>
</div>

<div class="draggable">
    <p>a plant with white berries that feeds on trees</p>
</div>

<div class="draggable">
    <p>breakfast and lunch combined in one meal</p>
</div>

<div class="draggable">
    <p>a part of a room used for cooking</p>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#wraper{
background: #FAFAFA;
border: 1px solid #333;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 20px;
width: 500px;
}
.draggable{
background: #F1F7FF;
border: 1px solid #CAE1FF;
display: inline;
float: left;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
padding: 3px;
position: relative;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
.draggable p{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.draggable p {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You shouldn't need the explicit `auto` width/height, that's the default. You normally wouldn't use `display: inline` either as a float is never inline, but I guess this is a workaround for an IE bug?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding `white-space:nowrap;` to the `.draggable` class.
2. If that fails, and you want a line break at a certain point, add `clear:left;` to the first instance of `.draggable` on each line.

BTW you could use inheritance, lose the `.draggable` class and `div` (BTW `wraper` = `wrapper`?) and just style the `p` tag:

```
#wrapper p { rules here }
```